# Issue with Task Due Date

Tags: apex, tasks, timezone

I need to compare the task due date against Now() to check if a task was within SLA.  Now I am facing a problem with the timezone. Due Date field is not storing the time. How to get the time gap between now and Due Date(activitydate) based on logged in users timezone?

Comment: Why don't you use system.today() rather than now()? Compare Date with Date, not Date with Datetime unless you know the time for the other date

Comment: Yes, but I need time gap as well. I want to show like this: 6Days 4hrs 30mins

Comment: Due Date is a Date field and NOW() is a Date/Time, so what time of day are you going to assume Due Date refers to? 12AM? 12PM?

Comment: As per @JeremyNottingham's comment, I'd suggest to create a new DateTime instance of the Date and explicitly set the time you want it to be, then compare against now().

Comment: As mentioned in developer docs, Due Date Field has a timestamp that is always set to midnight in the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) time zone.